# Django NoReverseMatch error on linking to DetailView

Tags: python, django, http, django-tables2

Am having trouble with linking to my DetailView from the main view of reporters. Both Urls are OK. I know this problem is well documented but the URLS are very confusing and I can't seem to find a solution out there. 
Here is the code for my views.py, table.py (Error is due to a line in this), urls.py.

Help will be greatly appreciated. 
Links are /reporters/ which should link to /reporters/pk/detail 
`

```
tables.py 
    import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2.utils import A
from models import Reporter

class ReporterTable(tables.Table):
    #my error is on the next time. It works for #list_all but not detail. 
    id = tables.LinkColumn('mysite.apps.reporters.views.detail', args=[A('pk')])
    class Meta:
        model = Reporter
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        fields = ('id', 'surname', 'othername', 'gender')

class ReporterViewTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Reporter
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from tables import ReporterTable, ReporterViewTable

from models import Reporter

class ReporterDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Reporter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReporterDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

def index(request):
    table = ReporterTable(Reporter.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'reporters/index.html', {'table':table})

urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from views import ReporterDetailView

urlpatterns = patterns('mysite.apps.reporters.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'), 
    url(r'^list_all/$', 'list_all'), 
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/detail/$', ReporterDetailView.as_view(template_name='reporters/detail.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<reporter_id>\d+)/edit/$', 'edit'),

)

index.html

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'reporters/style.css' %}" />
{% if table %}
<div>
    {%render_table table %}
</div>
{% else %}
    <p>No Reporters are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks a lot!

Here is the full exception header.

```
NoReverseMatch at /reporters/
Reverse for 'mysite.apps.reporters.views.detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

The entire exception is in this paste bin [here](http://dpaste.com/1758106/).

Comment: Can you post the full text of the exception?

Comment: @ACGray I added the text at the bottom with link to entire exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a directly imported class-based view you need to give your view a name to refer to it from elsewhere:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('mysite.apps.reporters.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'), 
    url(r'^list_all/$', 'list_all'), 
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/detail/$', ReporterDetailView.as_view(template_name='reporters/detail.html'), name='reporter_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<reporter_id>\d+)/edit/$', 'edit'),
```

)

Then in your `ReporterTable`:

```
id = tables.LinkColumn('reporter_detail', args=[A('pk')])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. It fixed the problem. Now let me get on with more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`args` should be a tuple, so something like that instead of a list:

```
id = tables.LinkColumn('mysite.apps.reporters.views.detail', args=(A('pk'),))
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. That doesn't fix it.